# Trying to make a function return the longest string

Tags: python, string

Hey everyone I'm trying to define a function that can return the longest string in a list as this is what I have so far:

```
record = ['60', 'Edward St', 'NSW','4019']
def length(lists):
    a = 0 
    answer = ''
    for item in lists:
        x = len(item) 
    if x < a:
        a = x
        answer = item
    elif x == a:
        if item not in record:
    return answer
print length(record)
```

But it keeps coming up with errors, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: under your if item not in record statement, you are not declaring nothing, so either your return answer is not indented properly, or you are missing an operation under the mentioned if statement

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows.

```
record = ['60', 'Edward St', 'NSW','4019']
def length(lists):
    a = 0 
    answer = ""
    for item in lists:
        x = len(item) 
        if x > a:
            a = x
            answer = item
    return answer
print (length(record))
```

What you did wrong?

1. `if x<a`, this should be x>a, because we have to check whether the existing longest word's length is smaller than the current word's length.
2. `elif` part is not required. The code will return the first longest word, if there are 2 words with the same length.

Otherthan that, you are correct.

**Edit**:

Fixed to work with python 3.x

Comment: This is working is python 2.7 but I need it to work in 3.5

Comment: Fixed it. just added brackets in the print.

Comment: This has a bug if the list is not all strings - e.g. `record = [[], {}]` then the output should either be an empty list or an empty dictionary, but it returns an empty string.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler `I'm trying to define a function that can return the longest string in a list`. Even though I agree with you, at this point, it won't be a poblem since he is using a list of strings.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha Good point. (But you could easily address it by starting `a=-1` instead of `a=0`, because len() will never return less than 0)

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha thank you so much to everyone! This really helped.

Answer (score 7):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) will find the maximum value from an iterable, and you can provide it a function to tell it how to compare them. Here, telling it to compare items by their length.

```
record = ['60', 'Edward St', 'NSW', '4019']

print(max(record, key=lambda s: len(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really simply

```
record = ['60', 'Edward St', 'NSW','4019']
def length(lists):
    a = 0
    ans = -1
    answer = ''
    for ind, item in enumerate(lists):
        x = len(item)
        if x>a:
            a = x
            ans=ind
    return lists[a]
print length(record)
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but it's meant to return the longest string so "edward st" not "4019", is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @s.chitti that is what will be returned

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
def length(lists):
    a = 0 
    answer = ''
    for item in lists:
        x = len(item) 
        if x > a:
            a = x
            answer = item
    return answer
```